# Was ist der “Stangenwinkel “ bei einem Brunnen?

Tags: meaning

Ich lese gerade Stifters [Brigitta](http://gutenberg.spiegel.de/buch/brigitta-198/2). Ich bin noch gar nicht weit gekommen, da stoße ich auf den unbekannten Begriff „Stangenwinkel“

> Ich war über hundert Bächlein, Bäche und Flüsse gegangen, ich hatte oft bei Hirten und ihren zottigen Hunden geschlafen, ich hatte aus jenen einsamen Haidebrunnen getrunken, die mit dem furchtbar hohen Stangenwinkel zum Himmel sehen, und ich hatte unter manchem tief herabgehenden Rohrdache gegessen – dort lehnte der Sackpfeifer, dort flog der schnelle Fuhrmann über die Haide, dort glänzte der weiße Mantel des Roßhirten – – oft dachte ich mir, wie denn mein Freund in diesem Lande aussehen werde; denn ich hatte ihn nur in Gesellschaft gesehen, und in dem Getriebe, wo sich alle Menschen, wie die Bachkiesel gleichen.

Ich habe natürlich Dr. Google gefragt, doch die Resultate erscheinen mir unbrauchbar — mit Ausnahme vielleicht eines [Resultates](https://books.google.at/books?id=iGI8KhQYdaoC&pg=PA240&lpg=PA240&dq=Stangenwinkel&source=bl&ots=F9Ws-nvw9o&sig=gMEjSn6GhMwslwwgePTknv2Rex8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5wZq128HXAhVFCMAKHe18BGIQ6AEIWTAM#v=onepage&q=Stangenwinkel&f=false); eines Textes der mit Kurbeln zu tun hat.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ich vermute, dass hier mit *Stangenwinkel* die Winkelstange eines Schwengelbrunnens gemeint ist.

[image: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trübenbach-Brunnen.jpg]
[https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Trübenbach-Brunnen.jpg](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Tr%C3%BCbenbach-Brunnen.jpg)

Aus Brunnen muss man ja Wasser schöpfen können. Dazu waren zwei Methoden sehr verbreitet:

- Ein Kübel hängt an einem Seil, dass mit einer Winde auf- und abgewickelt werden kann.
- Ein Kübel hängt an einer Konstruktion aus drei Stangen, wie sie im Bild zu sehen ist.

Die Stange, die an ihrem Mittelpunkt durch ein Gelenk (oft auch nur ein Auflager) mit dem oberen Ende der Stützstange verbunden ist, ist die Winkelstange, sie heißt auch *Schwengel*. An ihr hängt die Schöpfstange, und daran dann der Schöpfkübel.

Solche Stangen sieht man an vielen Brunnen, und sie ragen hoch in den Himmel, daher bin ich eigentlich sehr davon überzeugt, dass diese Stange dem entspricht, was Herr Stifter gemeint hat. Warum er allerdings »Stangenwinkel« statt »Winkelstange« geschrieben hat, weiß ich nicht.

---

Das Rohrdach ist übrigens ein Dach aus Schilfrohr. Beides zusammen (Rohrdächer und Brunnen mit Stangenwinkeln) kann man auch heute noch häufig rund um den Neusiedlersee sehen, also auch im Westen Ungarns, und somit genau dort, wo Stifters Erzählung ihren Anfang nimmt.

Comment: +1 für den Schwengelbrunnen. Wer weiß denn sowas? :)

Comment: Ist das Foto von Dir oder Public Domain? Wenn nein, bitte Quellenangabe.

Comment: @Takkat: Public Domain (aus Wikipedia)

Comment: @RoyPJ: Ich bin aus dem Osten Österreichs, da ist es nicht weit ins Burgenland, zum Neusiedlersee, daher sind mir diese Brunnen seit meiner Kindheit wohlbekannt. Man kennt sie auch unter dem Namen Puszta-Brunnen, weil sie eben für die ungarische Puszta sehr typisch sind. Einen Schwengel (der Name kommt vom Auf- und Abschwingen dieses Hebels) findet man auch bei modernen Hand-Brunnenpumpen, die daher auch »Schwengelpumpen« heißen und nach genau demselben Prinzip wie die beschriebenen Brunnen-Schöpfwerke arbeiten. (Google zeigt die gerne tausende Bilder von Schwengelpumpen.)

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: das Bild ist unter [CC by SA 3.0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/de/legalcode) lizensiert, das ist **nicht Public Domain**. Mit der jetzt dankenswerterweise erfolgten Quellennennung und weil auch wir unter CC by SA 3.0 lizensieren erfüllen wir nun die erforderlichen Bedingungen zur Weiterverbreitung.